# Prime factorisation in C++ using Fermat's Method

Tags: c++, factors

I am currently working on a program in C++, the ultimate goal of which is to display a list of prime factors for a given value, up to the limit of `unsigned long int`.

It takes advantage of trial division for the first 1000 prime numbers, and uses Fermat's Method of Factorisation for every value thereafter.

Generally, I'd say the program works okay for most numbers I've tested it with, including some larger numbers. However, I seem to have hit a snag with certain numbers. For example, when the prime number **18446744073709551557** is entered, it crashes entirely. For other larger values such as **246819835539726757**, it displays the first five prime factors (7, 11, 37, 131, and 557) correctly, but miscalculates the last two, which should be 18379 and 64601.

The code for the function is as follows:

```
std::list < unsigned long int >primeFactors(unsigned long int n)
{
    bool complete = false;
    std::list<unsigned long int> factors;
    unsigned long int ans1 = 0;
    unsigned long int ans2 = 0;
    int a;
    int b;

    // If n is 0 or 1, return a blank list
    //
    // This is run outside the while loop, as n will never be 0 or 1 after
    // the initial calculation
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
    {
        complete = true;
        return factors;
    }

    while (complete == false)
    {
        // if n is a prime number, add to the list and return
        if (isPrime(n) == true)
        {
            factors.push_back(n);
            complete = true;
            return factors;
        }

        // if n is even (i.e. divisible by 2), add 2 and n/2 to the list and
        // return
        else if (divisibleByPrime(n) != 0)
        {
            unsigned long int divisor = divisibleByPrime(n);

            ans1 = divisor;
            ans2 = n / divisor;


            if (isPrime(ans1) == true && isPrime(ans2) == true)
            {
                factors.push_back(ans1);
                factors.push_back(ans2);
                complete = true;
                return factors;
            }
            else
            {
                if (isPrime(ans1) == true)
                {
                    factors.push_back(ans1);
                    n = ans2;
                }
                else
                {
                    factors.push_back(ans2);
                    n = ans1;
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            // a is the square root of n + a^2
            unsigned long int i = 1;
            float squareRoot;
            std::stringstream ss;
            std::string str;
            bool isDouble = true;
            bool answerFound = false;

            unsigned long int x;
            unsigned long int y;

            while (answerFound == false)
            {
                isDouble = false;
                squareRoot = (float)sqrt(n + (i * i));
                ss << squareRoot;
                str = ss.str();
                for (char& i : str)
                {
                    if (strchr(".", i) != NULL)
                    {
                        isDouble = true;
                    }
                }
                if (isDouble == true)
                {
                    ss.str("");
                    i += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    answerFound = true;
                }
            }

            x = (unsigned long int) squareRoot;
            y = i;

            ans1 = x + y;
            ans2 = x - y;

            if (isPrime(ans1) == true && isPrime(ans2) == true)
            {
                factors.push_back(ans1);
                factors.push_back(ans2);
                complete = true;
                return factors;
            }
            else
            {
                if (isPrime(ans1))
                {
                    factors.push_back(ans1);
                    n = ans2;
                }
                else
                {
                    factors.push_back(ans2);
                    n = ans1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have not included functions such as `isPrime` or `divisibleByPrime` as both seem to work fine in an isolated environment.

**EDIT:** I appreciate certain variables are such are a little messy at the minute, but I plan on rectifying that soon.

Comment: Could be an overflow somewhere. Can you post a fully compilable version on https://ideone.com/ or so?

Comment: @Pavel Sure. https://ideone.com/rJiX6P

Comment: I spotted `complete == true;` which should be `complete = true;`.  Always compile with warnings enabled!

Comment: @HenriMenke Whoops, I thought I'd gotten rid of the last of those.

Comment: @HenriMenke: great catch!

Comment: If you have the Clang sanitizer available, you should compile with `-fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow`.  It is quite possible that you have an overflow situation, after all 18446744073709551557 = 2⁶⁴-1 = `ULONG_MAX`.

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't, unfortunately. However, I have a series of pre-defined tests, which are providing negative values in some cases so there's definitely an overflow. How could I go about preventing the overflow whilst ensuring that I still get the correct answers?

Comment: @RobDudley By writing correct code.